# Print DataFrame columns in an organized way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, format

I'm trying to print the columns of a data frame in an easy to read way. Currently my code looks like this:

```
In [ ]:

import pandas as pd

def printmastercolumns():
    
    columncount = 0
    for col in masterdf.columns:
        columncount += 1
        #prints each column with a number and a divider '|'
        print(columncount," ",col ,end =" | ")

masterdf = pd.read_csv(r'C:\master.csv')
printmastercolumns()

Out [ ]:

1   Customer | 2   Name | 3   Address1 | 4   Address2 | 5   City | 6   Zip/Postal | 7   State/Prov | 8   Mailing Address1 | 9   Mailing Address2 | 10   Mailing City | 11   Mailing State/Prov | 12   Mailing Zip/Postal | 13   Fax | 14   Toll Free | 15   SalesRep | 16   Comments | 17   CreditLimit | 18   Business Partner Info1 | 19   Info3 | 20   Info 5 |
```

But I would rather the output looks more like this:

```
Out [ ]:

1   Customer   | 7   State/Prov          | 13   Fax                    | 19   Info3  |
2   Name       | 8   Mailing Address1    | 14   Toll Free              | 20   Info 5 |
3   Address1   | 9   Mailing Address2    | 15   SalesRep               |
4   Address2   | 10  Mailing City        | 16   Comments               |
5   City       | 11  Mailing State/Prov  | 17   CreditLimit            |
6   Zip/Postal | 12  Mailing Zip/Postal  | 18   Business Partner Info1 |
```

It doesn't have to be perfect. I'm just looking for a more organized way to display each column name with a number next to it.

Thank you!

UPDATE Answer:

```
In [ ]:
import pandas as pd
import cmd

def printmastercolumns():
    columncount = 0
    collist = []
    for col in masterdf.columns:
        # combine all column numbers and names as strings in a list
        columncount += 1
        countstr = str(columncount)
        col = countstr + " " + col
        ColList.append(col)
    # print the column list in columns using cmd
    cli = cmd.Cmd()
    cli.columnize(ColList, displaywidth=80)

masterdf = pd.read_csv(r'C:\master.csv')
printmastercolumns()

Out [ ]:

1 Customer   6 Zip/Postal        11 Mailing State/Prov  16 Comments             
2 Name       7 State/Prov        12 Mailing Zip/Postal  17 CreditLimit          
3 Address1   8 Mailing Address1  13 Fax                 18 Business Parter Info1
4 Address2   9 Mailing Address2  14 Toll Free           19 Info3                
5 City       10 Mailing City     15 SalesRep            20 Info 5
```

Comment: Just use enumerate, for example:
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(n, col)

Comment: Thanks, that enumerate function is handy. But I'm actually looking to print the data in multiple columns. Sorry I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a `\n` in the end of the print so every time
it displays a line it goes into a newline:

```
def printmastercolumns():
    
    columncount = 0
    for col in masterdf.columns:
        columncount += 1
        #prints each column with a number and a divider '|'
        print(columncount," ",col ,end =" | \n")
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. Sorry I should have specified that I'm looking to print the data in columns, not just one long list.